# Is there a way to access variables in a state in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 Dart classes:

- The first one is the main App
- The second one is a widget in the App, that gets build in a Listview Builder of the first class inside a Dismissible

I then want to subtract a value in the main class's state with a value in the widget's state, when the Dismissible gets swiped away.

**Is there any way of accessing the widget's state to get this value?**

Edit:

To be more specific on my idea: I have this time picker widget

[image]

This widget stores a time (the difference of the starting and ending time)

In the main class, a total time is calculated, based on all the picked time widgets and their time.

Once a time picker widget gets removed, however, I need to subtract its time from the total time.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: You can make the variable in the main class as a `top level static` variable.